# Any special code to surface mount two gang box for outlets undersink?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I need to add four outlets under my sink. I am going to supply the outlets with the (20A) power circuit from my dishwasher (9A); the dishwasher and garbage disposal are on separate circuits.

1. I was thinking to just mount a standard 2 gang plastic box on the back wall of the sink cabinet and wire things up with 20A yellow romex
2. Also I would convert my dishwasher to plug in.
3. I will also replace the dishwasher breaker from standard 20A to one with GFCI & AFCI.

I noticed the conduit going to my hard wired disposal has maybe a plastic sheath around it, is that something I should consider for the wire that was originally going to dishwasher? And maybe even a sheath for the new dishwasher wire?

Under sink:

[image]

Behind Dishwasher:

[image]

Comment: Use a metal box (4x4 or 4-11/16x4-11/16) with an Exposed Work Cover for the receptacle/GFCI not a plastic box designed for use in the wall.

Comment: Gfci needed either at receptacle or breaker. AFCI as far as I know not required for kitchen receptacles

Comment: You probably don't need conduit; you can probably get by with smurf tube (ENT) between wall and cabinet.  Once the d/w is in place, the cable won't be subject to damage—the smurf tube would only be in case the d/w itself bottomed out against the cable.

Comment: @Huesmann , i liek that name quite fitting for the color. lol